# Slick Scala method inferred generic type

Tags: scala, generics, slick, traits

So I wanted to implement a trait to have a common execute function to run slick's query.

As you can see from the code below, I have one trait that has a type parameter on the class and the other define the type parameter on the method.

When I compile, the trait with method generic type compiles(without giving any type argument) but the other one does not.

Why??? I tried to give the class type arguments UserTable or User (my slick table def and projected case class) but none of them works. The error just says "expects DBIO[UserTable] but actual MySQLDriver.StreamingDriverAction"

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks a lot!!!

```
class DAO @Inject()(val configProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends 
    ManagementAppDatabase {
    private val users = TableQuery[UserTable]

  def findUserByEmail(email: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
    execute(users.filter(_.email === email).result.headOption)
  }
}

trait ManagementAppDatabase {
  val configProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider
 def execute[T](dBIO:DBIO[T]): Future[T] = configProvider.get[JdbcProfile].db.run(dBIO)
}

trait ManagementAppDatabase[T] {
  val configProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider
 def execute (dBIO:DBIO[T]):Future[T]=configProvider.get[JdbcProfile].db.run(dBIO)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend e.g. `ManagementAppDatabase[User]`, then you can only call `execute` on `DBIO[User]`. But `users.filter(_.email === email).result.headOption` is `DBIO[Option[User]]`. That's it.

Comment: Ahh I see thanks a lot! And just an add-on question if could answer as well I would really appreciate it. So how does Scala infer the type argument in this case (since I didn't give any concrete type argument)? And/or how does Scala infer types like this in general?

Comment: In this case `execute` doesn't have a type parameter to infer in the first place. And answering the second won't fit into a question.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a separate question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381289/scala-method-inferred-generic-type) Really appreciate it if you could answer!